# Prevent junit tests from running twice

Tags: java, junit, playframework

There are many similar questions to my questions,but there is no clear answer for it!
My tests are failing because they are running once inside suite and once alone. And I need them to run only once inside suite.
This is my suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Test1.class, Test2.class})
{
.....
}
```

I am running the test from the command line with command `test`.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: Are you using maven to run the tests

Comment: While yes, running two times may be annoying/slow, they **must not be failing**. If only running one time is a requirement for running successfully, then there is something wrong with the testing structure

Comment: the problem with running twice. is that the second one runs independent. without the suite which means without @beforeClass and AfterClass. thats why its failing!

Comment: Could you refactor the Suite to be an ExternalResource implementation and then include it as a ClassRule in each suite?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following setup to run tests with JUnit, parallel, and they run only once:

```
@RunWith(ParallelSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

And I have a ParallelSuite.class:

```
package tests;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.internal.runners.*;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder;
import org.junit.runners.model.RunnerScheduler;

public class ParallelSuite extends Suite {
    public ParallelSuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError  {

        super(klass, builder);

        setScheduler(new RunnerScheduler() {

            private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

            public void schedule(Runnable childStatement) {
                service.submit(childStatement);
            }

            public void finished() {
                try {
                    service.shutdown();
                    service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```